# Closing cursors/database in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-database

Here is the code:

```
public List<XImage> getXImages()
{
    List<XImage> images = new ArrayList<XImage>();

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = String.format("SELECT %s, %s, %s FROM %s",
            A, B, C, TABLE);

    Cursor result = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (result.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String a = result.getString(0);
            String b = result.getString(1);
            String c = result.getString(2);

            XImage image = new XImage(a, b, c);
            images.add(image);
        }

        while (result.moveToNext());
    }

    result.close();
    database.close();

    return images;  
}
```

If after `result.close();` I put `database.close();` I get a runtime exception saying that it's trying to access SqliteDatabase while the connection is closed.

Does closing the cursor also close the database connection? If not, what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems before, in the end of every method that works with the database, I had `database.close();` and sometimes that throwed exceptions.

Remove `database.close();` from around your code, and keep only the cursor close statements, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you - but what is the reason for this?

Comment: @b85411 If you close the database, the cursors can no longer be read from.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling the method from different threads.

However in my opinion, the best practice is never close the database because `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` and `SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadablDatabase()` always return the same instance if `SQLiteOpenHelper.close()` hasn't been called. So calling method like yours would mess up the `SQLiteDatabase` instance's life cycle which rises exceptions.

You might want to check this link out:

http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection

or source code of `SQLiteOpenHelper` here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java